# F expression conjunction with Sum() is not working as expected

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

```
class Order(models.Model):
    pass

class OrderItems(models.Model):
    order = models.ForiegnKey(Order, related_name="items")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    supplier = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    purchase_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    trade_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,blank=False, null=False , default = 0.00)
    retail_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)


class OrderItemSalesTax(models.Model):
    order_item = models.ForiegnKey(OrderItems, related_name="sales_tax")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    percentage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

class OrderItemDiscount(models.Model):
    order_item = models.OneToOneField(OrderItem, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='discount')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    discount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    in_percentage = models.BooleanField()
```

I am using this query to calculate the total amount, but also deducting discount and adding Sales tax.

**Sum(F('items__sales_tax__percentage'))** value is 25, and I have verified it, querying the database. Right now I have only **One** order and **two** Items and Items have two **Sales Taxes** and **One Discount**

I am trying to Sum the **Sales taxes** to apply on discounted price, but I am getting the wrong result results. If I manually write **25** by replacing **Sum(F('items__sales_tax__percentage'))** then results are correct, is there anything wrong with my query ?

```
Order.objects.filter(customer__zone__distribution=get_user_distribution(request.user.id))\
                          .annotate( 
                              trade_price=Sum(F('items__trade_price') * F('items__quantity')),
                              tax = Sum(F('items__sales_tax__percentage')),
                              discounted_price = F('trade_price') * ExpressionWrapper(0.01 * (100 - Sum(F('items__discount__discount'))), output_field=DecimalField()),
                              total = F('discounted_price') + F('discounted_price') * Sum(F('items__sales_tax__percentage')) / 100
                          )
```

Comment: Your models are not inheriting from `models.Model`?

Comment: Just updated .. please can you now look ?

Comment: Your query is referencing the `Parent ` model but the `Parent` model is missing, can you please add that to question too. Edit: oops, I might be wrong, will check again

Comment: Parent is Order.. BTW i updated that as well

Comment: You are joining on multiple tables which causes your aggregations to give results you don't expect. Also please see how to write a [mre] the models you have shared and the query you share don't match and will result in an error when run (For example you write `items__trade_price` but `OrderItems` has no `trade_price` field, you write `items__discount__discount` but I don't see any such relation or field in the code). The code you share should reproduce the problem you state and not any other errors.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I am sorry, i missed that part.. Please check now.. i have updated the Models